# Emulator Screen Issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

My emulator screen and activity_main.xml screen different. so I can't change position. How can I fix? Thanks

[Emulator View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LDKq.png)

[Android Studio View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHh1D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `constraint layout` and try using `Relative Layout` instead.

Or Simply put this code in your xml layout file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ali.haris.yourgoldennumber.Activites.AboutUs">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Ruhi Koyun Android App" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Click Me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how can I remove?

Comment: In your layout file you will see `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>&</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>` tags in the top & Bottom, remove it and replace it with `<RelativeLayout> & </RelativeLayout>`.